# Needing to filter a list by a predicate

Tags: java, list, dictionary, arraylist, filtering

I have a list containing several items, each containing a timestamp, a BigInt value and an alphabetic code, as follows:

| Timestamp | Value | Code |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2024-01-10 00:20:00 | 105.50 | I |
| 2024-01-15 02:30:00 | 105.50 | A |
| 2024-01-16 10:45:00 | 110.50 | A |
| 2024-02-01 12:20:00 | 111.25 | I |
| 2024-02-04 04:35:00 | 111.25 | A |
| 2024-02-25 02:15:00 | 112.25 | A |

I need to select all records where the year, month and value are the same; would be the duplicate occurrences. Of these duplicates, I wanted to keep only the first one, and eliminate the others. The `Code` value can be "A" or "I", and it is indifferent. Non-duplicate records must remain in the same order as the original list.

A example of filtered list:

| Timestamp | Value | Code |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2024-01-10 00:20:00 | 105.50 | I |
| 2024-01-16 10:45:00 | 110.50 | A |
| 2024-02-01 12:20:00 | 111.25 | I |
| 2024-02-25 02:15:00 | 112.25 | A |

How can I do this?

I have tryed .filter(), and .map(), without satisfactory results.

Comment: Does each item contain any information other than timestamp, value, and code?  Are you permitted to modify the item class?

Comment: I'd probably make a wrapper class the implements `equals` and `hashSet` accordingly then you can do `LinkedHashSet<RecordWrapper> set = recs.stream().map(RecordWrapper::new).collect(Collectors.toCollection(LinkedHashSet::new));`

Comment: What is the data type of the timestamp? Did you mean `java.sql.Timestamp`? Or its replacement, `java.time.Instant`? Or `String`?

Answer (score 1):

Since stability is a requirement (order of list has to be preserved), the use of list.stream().distinct() is not an option.

In case your `equals` method checks exactly for the three columns mentioned, you could do something like:

```
ArrayList result = new ArrayList();
original.stream().forEach(i -> if (!result.contains(i)) result.add(i));
```

If the equals method is not suitable, all the items in result list can by checked by comparing the three values.

```
ArrayList result = new ArrayList();
original.stream().forEach(i -> {
   for (YourClass j : result) {
      if (<all three values are equal>) return;
   }
   result.add(i);
});
```

Note: If the list is huge and computation time (this code is in O(n^2)) is a problem, you could use the three column values to create a new value and put it to a HashSet. You would then call the contains on the HashSet and add the value i to the resultSet and the HashSet.

Answer (score 0):

1. Create a [Java] `record` that contains a `LocalDateTime`, a `BigDecimal` and a `String`.
2. Override method `equals` in the `record`.
3. Override method `hashCode` in the `record`.
4. Create a `List` of the `record`s.
5. Stream the `List` and collect to a `LinkedHashSet` as it will remove duplicates (determined according to the overridden `equals` and `hashCode` methods) and maintain order of addition of `record`s.

```java
import java.math.BigDecimal;
import java.time.LocalDateTime;
import java.time.Month;
import java.time.YearMonth;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collection;
import java.util.LinkedHashSet;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;

public class MyClass {
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        List<TsValCod> list = new ArrayList<>();
        list.add(new TsValCod(LocalDateTime.of(2024, 1, 10, 0, 20, 0),  new BigDecimal(105.50), "I"));
        list.add(new TsValCod(LocalDateTime.of(2024, 1, 15, 2, 30, 0), new BigDecimal(105.50), "A"));
        list.add(new TsValCod(LocalDateTime.of(2024, 1, 16, 10, 45, 0), new BigDecimal(110.50), "A"));
        list.add(new TsValCod(LocalDateTime.of(2024, 2, 1, 12, 20, 0), new BigDecimal(111.25), "I"));
        list.add(new TsValCod(LocalDateTime.of(2024, 2, 4, 4, 35, 0), new BigDecimal(111.25), "A"));
        list.add(new TsValCod(LocalDateTime.of(2024, 2, 25, 2, 15, 0), new BigDecimal(112.25), "A"));
        Object temp = list.stream()
                          .collect(Collectors.toCollection(() -> new LinkedHashSet()));
        Collection<?> set = (Collection<?>) temp;
        set.stream()
           .forEach(System.out::println);
    }
}

record TsValCod(LocalDateTime ts, BigDecimal val, String code) {
    public boolean equals(Object obj) {
        boolean equal = this == obj;
        if (!equal) {
            if (obj != null  &&  getClass().equals(obj.getClass())) {
                TsValCod other = (TsValCod) obj;
                LocalDateTime meTs = ts();
                LocalDateTime otherTs = other.ts();
                BigDecimal meVal = val();
                BigDecimal otherVal = other.val();
                if (meTs == null) {
                    if (otherTs == null) {
                        equal = true;
                    }
                    else {
                        equal = false;
                    }
                }
                else {
                    if (otherTs == null) {
                        equal = false;
                    }
                    else {
                        int meYear = meTs.getYear();
                        Month meMonth = meTs.getMonth();
                        int otherYear = otherTs.getYear();
                        Month otherMonth = otherTs.getMonth();
                        equal = meYear == otherYear  &&  meMonth.equals(otherMonth);
                    }
                }
                if (equal) {
                    if (meVal == null) {
                        if (otherVal == null) {
                            equal = true;
                        }
                        else {
                            equal = false;
                        }
                    }
                    else {
                        if (otherVal == null) {
                            equal = false;
                        }
                        else {
                            equal = meVal.equals(otherVal);
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        return equal;
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        int year = ts.getYear();
        int month = ts.getMonthValue();
        YearMonth ym = YearMonth.of(year, month);
        return ym.hashCode() + val.hashCode();
    }
}
```

Output when running above code:
(Override `toString` method of `TsValCod` to customize the output.)

```
TsValCod[ts=2024-01-10T00:20, val=105.5, code=I]
TsValCod[ts=2024-01-16T10:45, val=110.5, code=A]
TsValCod[ts=2024-02-01T12:20, val=111.25, code=I]
TsValCod[ts=2024-02-25T02:15, val=112.25, code=A]
```

Answer (score 0):

This could be done using traditional for loop, or fancy stream with functional style.

But the first thing is how do we define the key, which can be as simple as

`record ItemKey(int year, Month month, BigDecimal value) {}`
using record.

#### For loop approach

This is quite straight forward, we use a Set to keep track `ItemKey`
If the `ItemKey` is visited continue to next `Item`
otherwise add the `ItemKey` to the Set, and keep the `Item`

#### Functional style:

1. Group the Item with same ItemKey to a Map<ItemKey, List
2. In each Entry<ItemKey, List, we get the first Item

For this problem, there is no absolute answer on which approach is better, I would recommend choosing the way you are more comfortable with. For doing simple filtering, mapping, functional approach is handy and less error prone. But for more complex problem, it is usually easier to find a solution using loop.

```java
import static java.util.stream.Collectors.collectingAndThen;
import static java.util.stream.Collectors.groupingBy;
import static java.util.stream.Collectors.mapping;
import static java.util.stream.Collectors.toList;

import java.math.BigDecimal;
import java.time.LocalDateTime;
import java.time.Month;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.LinkedHashMap;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Set;
import java.util.function.Function;

public class GroupFindFirst {
    // define how your key
    record ItemKey(int year, Month month, BigDecimal value) {
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        List<Item> items = List.of(
                new Item(LocalDateTime.parse("2024-01-10T00:20:00"), new BigDecimal("105.50"), "I"),
                new Item(LocalDateTime.parse("2024-01-15T02:30:00"), new BigDecimal("105.50"), "A"),
                new Item(LocalDateTime.parse("2024-01-16T10:45:00"), new BigDecimal("110.50"), "A"),
                new Item(LocalDateTime.parse("2024-02-01T12:20:00"), new BigDecimal("111.25"), "I"),
                new Item(LocalDateTime.parse("2024-02-04T04:35:00"), new BigDecimal("111.25"), "A"),
                new Item(LocalDateTime.parse("2024-02-25T02:15:00"), new BigDecimal("112.25"), "A")
        );
        System.out.println("filter using for loop");
        filterUsingForLoop(items).forEach(System.out::println);
        System.out.println("filter using stream");
        filterUsingStream(items).forEach(System.out::println);
    }

    private static List<Item> filterUsingForLoop(List<Item> items) {
        Set<ItemKey> itemKeys = new HashSet<>();
        List<Item> filtered = new ArrayList<>();
        for (Item item : items) {
            // add return true when ItemKey not exist before
            if (itemKeys.add(new ItemKey(item.timestamp.getYear(), item.timestamp.getMonth(), item.value))) {
                filtered.add(item);
            }
        }
        return filtered;
    }

    private static List<Item> filterUsingStream(List<Item> items) {
        return items.stream().collect(collectingAndThen(
                groupingBy(
                        item -> new ItemKey(item.timestamp.getYear(), item.timestamp.getMonth(), item.value),
                        LinkedHashMap::new, // to preserve order
                        mapping(Function.identity(), toList())),
                itemKeyToListMap -> itemKeyToListMap.values().stream().map(list -> list.get(0)).toList()
        ));
    }

    public static class Item {
        public Item(LocalDateTime timestamp, BigDecimal value, String code) {
            this.timestamp = timestamp;
            this.value = value;
            this.code = code;
        }

        @Override
        public String toString() {
            return "Item{" +
                    "timestamp=" + timestamp +
                    ", value=" + value +
                    ", code='" + code + '\'' +
                    '}';
        }

        private LocalDateTime timestamp;
        private BigDecimal value;
        private String code;
    }

}
```